CoUninitialize raises a "fail fast exception" in DLL
I am using a library (RtAudio) that calls CoInitialize/CoUninitialize and everything worked smoothly until I tried to move my code into a dll. Now, when I free the dll during shutdown, the debugger (MSVS'22) stops at a call of CoUninitizalize and tells me

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF98BF52F62 (KernelBase.dll) in App.exe: 0xC0000602:  A fail fast exception occurred. Exception handlers will not be invoked and the process will be terminated immediately.

I placed some breakpoints at each call of CoInitiaize and CoUninitialize and noticed that each is called twice. At the second call of CoUninitialize (which is in the destructor of a global static object) I get the fail fast exception. Afaik I cannot even catch and suppress this type of error.
I read here on stackoverflow several times now that it is not a good idea to call CoInitialize/CoUninitialize in a dll and that this should be left to the host application, but I cannot really change this, unless by editing 3rd-party code.
Is there some way to prevent this? What is even the reason for the issue? I don't really get the problem since the init/uninit calls are actually balanced.
(using platform toolset v143)

What is the return value of CoInitilize? Is it perhaps : RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE? Anyway I recommend you to use ::CoInitializeEx. Probable reason the main executable already initialized COM with a different appartment model.  If you want full control of your own threading model, run all your code on a background (workerthread) that you CoInitializeEx yourself.

The first call of CoInitialize returns S_OK, the second returns S_FALSE. The first call of CoUninitialize succeeds, the second raises the exception. I realize it is recommended to use CoInitializeEx, but as I said, it's 3rd party code and I would really prefer to use it as-is, if possible. I would rather move to a different library entirely.

It's not recommended to CallInitializeEx instead of CoInitialize, it just depends on how you want to initialize COM (duh). CoInitialize(Ex) must only be called by the developer who initializes the thread in which COM will run (for the process's initial  thread, it must be called by process creator too). Doing otherwise (ie: calling it in random code/library/etc.) is a bug that should be fixed. That being said calling CoInitialize should generally be harmless (but may give false impression), however, calling CoUnitialize is clearly not, as some COM messages can be pending somewhere.

Not entirely sure if what you're saying is that surrounding my LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary with another CoInitializeEx/CoUninitialize is a solid solution? I tried it and it worked, thus the first init is within the host code and the last uninit is as well. This way, it does not crash, at least if I init with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED. But this is, as it seems, now a bug in the RtAudio code because it does not check for the return code and still tries to uninit, even if RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE was returned, which causes an unbalanced call and seems like an issue?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008037/debugging-a-crash-while-unloading-dll-in-win-10-but-not-win-7

Issue is not unbalanced, issue is generally a call to CoUnitialize in the wrong place. The only "solid solution" is for the creator of threads (or process) to call CoInitialize(Ex) at beginning of thread (or process) and call CoUninitialize when the thread (or process) is finished. No library/code should ever call these fonctions but inform their callers they expects COM to be initialized. The rest are hacks that may work.

@SimonMourier alright, thanks!
